# Product Catalog - Document Store or Column Family Store

Tags: nosql, document-store

Wondering which technology would do better for a typical product catalog of a webshop. I'm writing my master thesis about nosql in the enterprise environment and focused on document stores for to long now I think.
Read a lot articles which recommend document stores because of it's flexibilty which is needed to model thousands of different products. But as far as I know now, Column-Family Stores like Cassandra offer the same flexibility.

What I like most of the idea of using cassandra is, what nosql-database.org says about it (marked the most interesting features):

> massively **scalable**, partitioned row store, masterless architecture, linear scale performance, **no single points of failure**, read/write support across multiple data centers & cloud availability zones. API / Query Method: CQL and Thrift, replication: peer-to-peer, written in: Java, Concurrency: **tunable consistency**, Misc: built-in data compression, MapReduce support, primary/secondary indexes, **security features**.

In the end I focus on building a prototype of a highly available and scaleable Multishop System which makes use of polyglot persistence, saying K/V Stores for Sessions, Document Store or Column-Family Store for Product Catalog and maybe RDBMS for Inventory/Pricing like Sadalage and Fowler mentioned in their book "NoSQL Destilled".

If possible, provide scientific papers or other reliable sources for your answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Document Store's Achilles Heel

[Stuart Halloway](https://github.com/stuarthalloway) mentioned that a document store is the biggest schema lock solution that is way too inflexible, which I agree with. Couch/Mongo and others try to mitigate that by providing workarounds to create secondary indicies, ability and necessity to be aware of plain object ids, etc. And of course if you think about versioning (i.e. add a "time" variable to your system), document stores fail fast to provide a smooth support and time travel.

### Column Store: Problem Relevance

Cassandra is a really compelling solution for building "scalable"/"distributed" systems with real examples such as Netflix, where 500 Cassandra nodes can be brought up in AWS for several minutes, and all the requests hit a Cassandra ring.

However, given the problem as it is stated in your question, Cassandra would be an unnecessary overkill. Not just because it is a bit more complex than "others", or because it is mentally harder to create a solid data model on top of column oriented stores, but also because a "product catalog" problem is not quite a rocket science. It can be, if you want to add machine learning later to predict/recognize/etc.., but a catalog itself is not, and simpler stores such as [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) for example would solve it easily.

### Simple Desire to NoSQL

If you really *want* to use NoSQL for a product catalog, I would definitely consider 3 solutions to fit your prototype:

- [Riak](http://basho.com/riak/) as a "K/V for Sessions"
- [Datomic](http://www.datomic.com/) to solve "Product Catalog, Inventory and Pricing"
- Depending on the size and nature of the problem and the final solution, I would consider [Redis](http://redis.io/) to cache those sessions, while having Datomic comfortably sit on top of Riak as its storage service.

### Practice vs. Theory

Two classical NoSQL papers that made NoSQL sound real in practice for the first time are [Dynamo](http://www.read.seas.harvard.edu/%7Ekohler/class/cs239-w08/decandia07dynamo.pdf) and [BigTable](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf). I consider Datomic to be the next evolutionary step in the DB universe by introducing a hybrid data model with *true indicies* and *relations* without a schema lock, and *immutability* from which everything follows: safe time travel, caching, local db values, etc.

Practically, if it wasn't a master theses, depending on the real problem scale and definition, I would be choosing between Datomic and PostreSQL to solve catalog, inventory, pricing, etc.

- A big advantage of Datomic here is time travel. In practice it is very important to be able to safely and easily do that in a "Shopping System".
- A big advantage of PostgreSQL is its familiarity and SQL tools availability for analytics and reporting.

Comment: Hi tolitius,
even if I don't agree with your first statement the rest of the comment was quite helpful for me ;)
I did not have Datomic on my map so I will take a closer look at it.
I think PostgreSQL will not fit my needs since it is not flexible enough and in addition it does not scale well horizontally like any other RDBMS I tink.
The idea with Redis as a cache I will also evaluate!

Comment: I understand the first statement may sound controversial and does depend on a problem, however using document stores on different projects I just came to the same conclusion as Stuart, so I'll leave it up to your personal experience. Any DB store can be tweaked to work, but I believe Foursquare would not use Mongo if they started today. As far as Postgres and horizontal scale, if you agree with me that Instagram is a "large enough" system, that is [how they do it](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram).

Answer (score 3):

By now I think that Column-Family Stores are not well suited for product calaloges.
It's because products often contain some kind of collections like tags, tracklists for music records, different sizes for clothes and so on.

Cassandra [supports collections](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html#cassandra/ddl/ddl_anatomy_table_c.html#concept_ds_qnt_w2z_zj) by now BUT they are not searchable! This is a must have feature for tags for example.
In contrast MongoDb for example offers the [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in) operator to search in nested arrays...

I don't want to say it is not possible to model a product calalog in Cassandra but I think it is much more straight forward to do it in a document store.